# SSIS Oracle Query Returns No rows

Tags: sql-server, ssis, oracle10g

I ran the query in SQL Developer (Oracle's tool), copied it over to SSIS, clicked Preview and it returns nothing. It works fine in Oracle. Any ideas? It does take about 120 seconds to run in Oracle.

Comment: FYI, it's an OLE DB Data Source task

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question but it has to be asked: is SSIS connecting to Oracle with the same user you're using in SQL Developer?

Comment: Yes it is connecting with the same use.

Comment: There is no error. Just no data.

Comment: Are you using the MS drivers?  If so, I highly recommend switching to the Oracle drivers (installed w/ Oracle Client Services.)  It's not an easy installation, but is a big improvement over the MS supplied drivers.

Comment: bingo! it was the drivers. I changed to an ODBC datasource using the Oracle drivers and it worked. What kind of flowers do you like Data Masseur?

Comment: Just a note for the Oracle drivers for Windows. Look at the Instance Client version. A very small footprint on the server and installation is very simple. As far as I know they started providing this for Oracle 10 and up. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html

Answer (score 0):

Preview has a 30 second timeout which you can't extend AFAIK. This is possibly why you can't preview.

Try adding a dummy transform (e.g. a Multicast) downstream, and then adding a Data Viewer on the Data Flow Path between the two.

Answer (score 0):

I see this post has been dormant for awhile, but I found adding `UseSessionFormat=True;` to the end of your connection string solved the problem.